# Loop to Update Labels in PyQT GUI

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

I have a pyqt gui that among other things, has labels that are populated with data on init.  The labels themselves are easy to update with:

```
self.ui.mylabel_1.setText('foobar')
self.ui.mylabel_2.setText('foobar')
```

Is there any way I can loop over this in a similar way to do this as in my following pseudo:

```
for num in range (1,24):
   self.ui.mylabel_num.setTest('foobar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way to do this is to store a list of all your labels somewhere, i.e. `self.all_labels = [self.ui.mylabel_1, self.ui.mylabel_2]` and then doing `for label in self.all_labels: label.setTest('foobar')`.

You could also use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to make your example work:

```
for num in range (1,24):
   label = getattr(self.ui, 'mylabel_{}'.format(num))
   label.setTest('foobar')
```

Comment: The getattr method works great and solved some other problems for me.  Thanks!