# PyQt4: existing text box and buttons deleted, but didn't showing new lables

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Here i have created UI using pyqt4 for one file processing method. OOPs concept used here for the implementation. First select the path by using browse button and the path inserted into text box

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QPixmap

class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)


class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.labl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('-VDT')


        self.logo=QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(QPixmap("logo.jpg"))
        self.logo.move(130, 30)

        self.browse_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.browse_btn.move(430, 110)

        self.start_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.start_btn.move(150, 200)
        self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(80, 110)
        self.textbox.resize(330, 25)


        self.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.dialog = Second(self)

    def browse(self):
        file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))

        self.textbox.setText(file)


    def start(self):
        # self.dialog.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        # self.dialog.show()
        dir_path= self.textbox.text()
        print(dir_path)

        self.start_btn.deleteLater()
        self.browse_btn.deleteLater()
        self.textbox.deleteLater()

        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("Started Processing")
        self.label1.move(30, 110)

        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Total files")
        self.label2.move(30, 160)

        self.label3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label3.setText("Processed Files")
        self.label3.move(30, 210)

        Total_no_of_files= number
        self.label4 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label4.setText(Total_no_of_files)         #Have to add number of files in the selected folder
        self.label4.move(240, 160)


        self.label5 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label5.setText(Processed_no_of_files)  # Have to add number of files processing, this value will increment from 1 to total number of files
        self.label5.move(30, 210)               #



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While clicking the start button, the text box and buttons are removed by using deletelater() method. Then i have added few labels. Following are the issues.

**1) The image logo small portion is showing**

**2) Newly added labels are not showing**

**3) The newly added label5 value have to be change while it going through the process in a for loop. (in tkinter i have used intvar() and root.update() to do this)**

How can i solve this issues?

**Updated**
I have changed my code based on your answer, but the buttons and text boxes are not deleted and now the labels are over lapping with the old buttons and text box. Please see the following code

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QPixmap

class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)


class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.labl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('-VDT')


        self.logo=QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(QPixmap("logo.jpg"))
        self.logo.move(130, 30)
        self.logo.setVisible(True)
        self.browse_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.browse_btn.move(430, 110)

        self.start_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.start_btn.move(150, 200)
        self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(80, 110)
        self.textbox.resize(330, 25)


        self.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.dialog = Second(self)

    def browse(self):
        file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))

        self.textbox.setText(file)


    def start(self):
        # self.dialog.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        # self.dialog.show()
        dir_path= self.textbox.text()
        print(dir_path)
        list_dir = os.listdir(dir_path)
        dir_length = len(list_dir)
        self.start_btn.deleteLater()
        self.browse_btn.deleteLater()
        self.textbox.deleteLater()
        self.logo.setVisible(True)
        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("Started Processing")
        self.label1.move(30, 110)
        self.label1.setVisible(True)
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Total files")
        self.label2.move(30, 160)
        self.label2.setVisible(True)
        self.label3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label3.setText("Processed Files")
        self.label3.move(30, 210)
        self.label3.setVisible(True)
        Total_no_of_files= dir_length
        self.label4 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label4.setText(str(dir_length))         #Have to add number of files in the selected folder
        self.label4.move(240, 160)
        self.label4.setVisible(True)
        self.label5 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label5.move(240, 210)
        self.label5.setVisible(True)



        path = dir_path
        TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
        # print(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
        Total_No_Files = len(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)

        import cv2
        comp_no_files=0
        for filename in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
            image_path= path+'//'+filename
            print(image_path)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            img = cv2.resize(image, (660, 340))
            cv2.imshow('Show Image', img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            comp_no_files += 1
            self.label5.setText(str(comp_no_files))




def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: **The image logo small portion is showing**, what does it mean?

Comment: The image didn't show fully even after **self.logo.move(130, 30)**

Comment: I'm sorry,  **The newly added label5 value have to be change while it going through the process in a for loop. (in tkinter i have used intvar() and root.update() to do this) **, what does it mean?

Comment: @user9402680 : Actually , the process is working number of files in a directory, I have used **for file in folder:** for loop in this program. First the label5 value will be 0, then process complete on 1st file , so the label5 value changed from 0 to 1,  then 2nd file completion, the label5 value changed from 1 to 2 and so on.

Comment: like the answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168353/loop-to-update-labels-in-pyqt-gui]

Comment: I understood what you mean.But from where do `number` and `Processed_no_of_files` valiables come?1 and 2 will be solved by my answer.at least, this is not excutable from your code soon.

Comment: Here the label5 value is initially 0.just for example.  `folder=['a','b','c','d']                                                                               for file in folder:  label5 value+=1  time.sleep(3)`

Comment: I updated,but I didn't find out any problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `setVisible(True)` on every labels.

**Why does labels not show after deleteLater()?**

`deleteLater()` makes no difference about your problem.

In `python`, basically, you prepare the settings before you show them.

`setGeometry()`,`setPixmap()`,set..... all of settings.

and when the parent widget shows, all of the settings are shown.

But the labels on the problem, the window has already been shown.

So, you must `setVisible(True)` clearly.

That is to say, you set the labels at the first time, in **init** constructor, the labels shows up soon.

I think there is exception about basic thought of `python`, I have no idea except for the reason.

1.2 is solved by setVisible(True).

for question 3,

It is important measure the number of directory.

**label5 issue**
Basically, `setText()` is executed once.
I recommend that you sometimes customize your code for counting the number during processing some actions,but it is not the time now.Because there is no necessity for doing it.

If you want to show the changing of the number,you execute it in the sequence or timeline.

If your folda is very big, and a great number of foldas you have, you can see naturally the changing for or while sequence.

```
for num in sequence:
    label5.setText(str(num))
```

but I understood you wanted to show the changing at any rate, so I used `QTimeLine`

from 0 to dir_length, 2000ms, the number will be changed after `QTimeLine.start()`
in the code.

It depends on you when you connect this way if you count the number of foldas.
I think I cannot say it clearly now.

I don't explain how to do it here.
please add these command.

```
import os #at the first line of your editor.
-----------------------------
dir_path= self.textbox.text() # under the function of start
print(dir_path)
list_dir = os.listdir(dir_path)
dir_length = len(list_dir)
```

on my occasion , as the result, please try this code.

**Updated**
In my case, it had no problem.Buttons and textboxes are hidden completely.
But in your case, it remains after pushing start-button.

I tried to change your code from `deleteLater()` to `setVisible(False)`

```
self.start_btn.setVisible(False
self.browse_btn.setVisible(False)
self.textbox.setVisible(False)
```

If you can't solve the problem,please give me a comment.

---

```
import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QPixmap

class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)


class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.labl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('-VDT')


        self.logo=QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(QPixmap("logo.jpg"))
        self.logo.move(130, 30)
        self.logo.setVisible(True)
        self.browse_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.browse_btn.move(430, 110)

        self.start_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.start_btn.move(150, 200)
        self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(80, 110)
        self.textbox.resize(330, 25)


        self.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.dialog = Second(self)

    def browse(self):
        file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))

        self.textbox.setText(file)


    def start(self):
        # self.dialog.setGeometry(550, 200, 550, 300)
        # self.dialog.show()
        dir_path= self.textbox.text()
        print(dir_path)
        list_dir = os.listdir(dir_path)
        dir_length = len(list_dir)
        self.start_btn.setVisible(False)
        self.browse_btn.setVisible(False)
        self.textbox.setVisible(False)
        self.logo.setVisible(True)
        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("Started Processing")
        self.label1.move(30, 110)
        self.label1.setVisible(True)
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Total files")
        self.label2.move(30, 160)
        self.label2.setVisible(True)
        self.label3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label3.setText("Processed Files")
        self.label3.move(30, 210)
        self.label3.setVisible(True)
        Total_no_of_files= dir_length
        self.label4 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label4.setText(str(dir_length))         #Have to add number of files in the selected folder
        self.label4.move(240, 160)
        self.label4.setVisible(True)
        self.label5 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label5.move(240, 210)
        self.label5.setVisible(True)



        path = dir_path
        TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
        # print(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
        Total_No_Files = len(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)

        import cv2
        comp_no_files=0
        for filename in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
            image_path= path+'//'+filename
            print(image_path)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            img = cv2.resize(image, (660, 340))
            cv2.imshow('Show Image', img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            comp_no_files += 1
            self.label5.setText(str(comp_no_files))




def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

after updating processed file is 1.because I have a jpg file.

[image: result]

Comment: You can use `os` (with python) and `QDir` (with PyQt4) class for handling files.I set the same number on the total number and processed number because I think it will be complete in the future.

Comment: The updated answer is not right, Total number of files in the directory is correct. Processed files will be change from 0 to len(Total number of files) with a time delay of 3 seconds (time.sleep(3)). Have to gone through a for loop like i mentioned in the comment part. At each iteration, the label5 value have to be changed.

Comment: @Kpras Yes,  I understand as you are talking,you want to count the number of folda gradually, and show it on the processed number.But it is very difficult to assume the process,because I don't have the necessity for it.I can't understand why you want to count them gradually...I can't imagine the reason.

Comment: That is to say, It seems that you dare to count it even if you don't need to count it, to me.I understand what you want.Yes, I try to do it as possible as I can.

Comment: okay.. actually this is working in images.. 1 minute will take to process on each image.. so i just want to display it

Comment: @Kpras I'm sorry, I reupdated because I had thought I could update my answer... It had not been updated...

Comment: I’m just going to accept your answer, please add image label and try to solve this label5 value issue

Comment: @Kpras please read my answer and if you can't understand,please hesitate to ask me.But when the question should be a new question,I can't answer for it.please write new question.

Comment: Maximum question limits reached, so i can't ask new question. Please see the updated question. Actually i have applied your suggestions into my code, but now the labels are overlapping

Comment: @Kpras I executed your code,but it had no problem.The buttons and lineedits are cleared completely.If you make the objects deleted,you use setVisible(False) instead of deleteLater()

Comment: Do you have any problem on stackoverflow community?Parhaps,did you delete your questions over and over again?At least,I thought I could answer your previous question completely even if there were still other points for improving.there is a possibility of penalty if you update your question on such a case.Please take care of youself.

Comment: Please answer the updated issue, I'm just facing the previous issue